# Add BitmapFont.draw from a Custom Actor to a ScrollPane/Table

Tags: java, libgdx

I have created a custom `Actor` called `TestScrollActor` which calls `BitmapFont.drawWraped` on its `draw` method.

The `CharSequence/Text` will be appended from time to time and for this reason I need to add this custom `Actor` to my vertical scrollable `Table`. The text is displayed correctly, but it does not scroll at all.

Here are my full working classes `MyStage` which implements `Screen` and my `Custom Actor`:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.LabelStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;

public class MyStage implements Screen{

    private BitmapFont font;
    private String text = "The modern encyclopedia was developed from the "
            + "dictionary in the 18th century. Historically, both encyclopedias "
            + "and dictionaries have been researched and written by well-educated, "
            + "well-informed content experts, but they are significantly different "
            + "in structure. A dictionary is a linguistic work which primarily focuses "
            + "on alphabetical listing of words and their definitions. Synonymous words "
            + "and those related by the subject matter are to be found scattered around "
            + "the dictionary, giving no obvious place for in-depth treatment. Thus, a dictionary "
            + "typically provides limited information, analysis or background for the word defined."
            + " While it may offer a definition, it may leave the reader lacking in understanding the meaning,"
            + " significance or limitations of a term, and how the term relates to a broader field of knowledge. "
            + "An encyclopedia is, allegedly, not written in order to convince, although one of its goals is indeed "
            + "to convince its reader about its own veracity. In the terms of Aristotle's Modes of persuasion, a "
            + "dictionary should persuade the reader through logos (conveying only appropriate emotions); it will be"
            + " expected to have a lack of pathos (it should not stir up irrelevant emotions), and to have little ethos "
            + "except that of the dictionary itself. To address those needs, an encyclopedia article is typically not limited to "
            + "simple definitions, and is not limited to defining an individual word, but provides a more extensive meaning for a "
            + "subject or discipline. In addition to defining and listing synonymous terms for the topic, the article is able to treat "
            + "the topic's more extensive meaning in more depth and convey the most relevant accumulated knowledge on that subject. "
            + "An encyclopedia article also often includes many maps and illustrations, as well as bibliography and statistics.";

    private Stage stage;

    public static float myGameWidth = 400;
    public static float myGameHeight = 640;

    @Override
    public void show() {

        stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(myGameWidth,myGameHeight));

        InputMultiplexer inputM = new InputMultiplexer();
        inputM.addProcessor(stage);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputM);

        font =  new BitmapFont();

        TextScrollActor textScrollActor = new TextScrollActor(text);

        //create scrollable table
        LabelStyle labelStyle = new LabelStyle();
        labelStyle.font = font;
        labelStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;

        final Table scrollTable = new Table();
        scrollTable.top();

        scrollTable.add(textScrollActor).height(300);
        scrollTable.row();

        final ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(scrollTable);

        final Table table = new Table();
        table.setSize(300, 400);
        table.setPosition(25, 300);
        table.add(scroller).fill().expand();

        this.stage.addActor(table);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //Update the stage
        stage.draw();
        stage.act(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void dispose() {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {dispose();}

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {}


    public class TextScrollActor extends Actor{

        private BitmapFont font;
        private String text;

        public TextScrollActor(String text) {
            this.text = text;

            font =  new BitmapFont();
            font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

            font.drawWrapped(batch,text,50, 450, 280);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. List item

Your problem is `TextScrollActor` of 0 size (W=0, H=0).

If you making you own actor and it has custom drawing function, you should always pay attention to it's width and height values and change it by yourself. `Actor` uses size of (0, 0) by default and different implementations change it according to content their drawing. So to make scroll works you just need to compute space that text takes (some of `BitmapFont#getBounds` methods should help you) and set that dimens to Actor width and height. That should work.

Other question is why do you implement your own actor? Because this case perfectly covers by `Label` with configured skin.

Comment: thanks @Metaphone...you are absolutely right, there is no need to create a custom actor, it works perfectly fine with just the label.
Thanks again